# Measure area polygon and distance with google map at the same time

Tags: javascript, html

i have an issue with the passage of value with a maps. The code create a polygon, and measure the area (in mq), and the distance (in mt). 
Code javascript:

```
function on_click_function(location_passed){
click_polygon.setMap(null);                             //  clears click_polygon from map
click_line.setMap(null);                                //  clears click_line from map
points_array.push(location_passed);                     //  push clicked lat lng into points array
if (document.getElementById("polygon_mode").checked){   //  create (or recreate) the click_polygon object
    create_polygon();
    click_polygon.setMap(my_map);
}
if (document.getElementById("line_mode").checked){      //  create or recreate the click_line
    create_line();
    click_line.setMap(my_map);
}
clear_markers();
rewrite_markers();
calculate_dimensions_and_display();
}// end on_click_function
```

and in html code:

```
<table id = "output_table">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="draw_mode" id = "line_mode" onclick = "mode_was_changed();" checked = "checked"/> Ora seleziona i vertici del tetto
            </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="draw_mode" id = "polygon_mode" onclick = "mode_was_changed();"  /> <!-- checked = "checked" --> Calcola l'area del tuo tetto
            </td>

            <td>Dimensioni: <span id="area">&nbsp;</span>
            </td>
            <td>Area: <span id="area">&nbsp;</span>
            </td>
```

The url are: app.tettosano.com/calculator.php
The user click radio button for to visualize or the area or the perimeter. But, i want what the user, when draw the polygon, it can visualize both area and perimeter in two box different, but at the same time.

How can i solve this issue?

Regards

Alessandro

Comment: You might want to tag this better - what has this got to do with PHP? There's no PHP code in your question. Ditto for mysql; and web is very generic.

Comment: You might want to create a minimal [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this, to make it easier to play around for yourself and others.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aletegagni/kF6XQ/1/  and the first time you use jsfiddle, I hope goes well.